# status of mpg123 player controlled using FIFO

Tags: linux, fifo

I have been controlling mpg123 player using fifo for some project work so far it's all good.

For fifo access

```
mpg123 -R --fifo "/root/work/voiFifo"
```

and supplying commands like

```
echo load 1.mp3 > /root/work/voiFifo
```

The thing is there any way to know whether 1.mp3 file is played through or still some part of it is remaining, because in between i may Pause/Resume it?